# How do I determine the correct browser version when compatability mode is turned on

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, internet-explorer

I need to determine which version of browser the user is using, however compatibility mode is turned on by default for the entire company.

On the server side script, how do I determine the real browser version?

Thanks

*Update*
I've got my page correctly showing the IE version using document.documentMode, however I can't figure out how to pass this over to the server side so I can use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect IE8 Compatibility Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328963/detect-ie8-compatibility-mode)

Comment: @Michael How do I do that server side though?  I use the result as part of a Linq query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.documentMode in javascript was the solution.

```
<script>
alert(document.documentMode);
<script>
```

Comment: in my case it will also alert 7 when i am using ie 8 under compatibility mode

Answer (score 4):

[Request.Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx) will give you complete browser information, where you can check version, browser name, browser type etc.

```
Request.Browser.Version // Return complete browser version infor
Request.Browser.Browser // If browser is IE then it will return **IE**
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the browser is using compatibility mode.  Request.Browser.Version returns 7.0 even though I am using IE9.  This is what I am trying to get around

Comment: @Matt Check this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/01/09/the-internet-explorer-8-user-agent-string-updated-edition.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than fighting compatibility mode, you can turn it off for your specific web application.   We do this on all of our sites because compatibility mode really screws a lot of things up.

[Force IE compatibility mode off using tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449286/force-ie-compatibility-mode-off-in-ie-using-tags)

Comment: I had a crack at that, but I couldn't make it work.  I'll look into it further though since it is a more elegant version than what i've currently got.

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent on server if on client then user navigator.userAgent 
and then instructions from below ie7 has no trident keyword but ie8 is trident/4 and IE5 is trident/5.

First look for MSIE x.x, if x.x is 7 then look for Trident/y.y.  If trident is missing then it IE7 if y.y is 4 then its IE8 and if y.y is 5 then ie9 and if y.y is 6 then ie10

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/23/introducing-ie9-s-user-agent-string.aspx