# Are IE8's Development Tools Browser and Document Modes the same as using IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

In Internet Explorer 8 when I bring up the Developer tools window (F12), it gives you the option to change browser mode and document mode.  I am need to test some scripts to see if they will be fine in IE 7 which is what my client runs on, but I only have IE 8 on my machine.

If I set Browswer Mode to IE 7 along with IE 7 standards for document mode is this the **exact** same as if I were to open my pages in the IE 7 browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differentiate IE7 browser and browser in IE7 compatibility mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213639/differentiate-ie7-browser-and-browser-in-ie7-compatibility-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing will be the **exact** same unless you really use IE7. However the differences are pretty insignificant and usually pretty low level or so specific, that 99% of the users (and even developers) will never notice or face them.

However you might want to install [this tool](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) as well. It's handy to have all those IE-s in one place for testing purposes.