# how to get compatible view status by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I got a web page which has problem with compatible view mode in IE. I'm going to display an alert to users which their browsers are in compatible view in order to fix it.

My question is: Is there any way to get compatible view status( is on or off) by java script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differentiate IE7 browser and browser in IE7 compatibility mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213639/differentiate-ie7-browser-and-browser-in-ie7-compatibility-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
```

this disables compatibility view

Comment: exactly What I have been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The [document.compatMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be used to check for compatibility mode and apparently works cross-browsers (verified with IE, Chrome, Firefox):

E.g., **Standard mode**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<title></title>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var navigator = window.navigator;
    info.firstChild.data =
        "\n navigator.userAgent: " + navigator.userAgent +
        "\n document.compatMode: " + document.compatMode;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<pre id="info">&nbsp;</pre>
</body>
```

Output:

```
 navigator.userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0)
 document.compatMode: CSS1Compat
```

**Compatibility mode**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "">
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var navigator = window.navigator;
    info.firstChild.data =
        "\n navigator.userAgent: " + navigator.userAgent +
        "\n document.compatMode: " + document.compatMode;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<pre id="info">&nbsp;</pre>
</body>
```

Output:

```
 navigator.userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0)
 document.compatMode: BackCompat
```