# how to know whether compatibility is on or off using asp.net(c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to do if user's browser compatibility is on then need to show message to user that your browser's compatibility is on.

I have searched this a lot on google but yet not found a proper answer.

I have tried below code but HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent always contains MSIE 7.0

```
string isOn = string.Empty;

if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("MSIE 7.0") > -1)
{
 isOn  = "IE8 Compatibility View";`   

    }
    else
    {
    isOn  = "IE8";
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differentiate IE7 browser and browser in IE7 compatibility mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213639/differentiate-ie7-browser-and-browser-in-ie7-compatibility-mode)

Comment: is there any way to find that compatibility is on or not

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this

```
if (Request.Browser.Type.ToUpper().Contains("IE"))
{
    if (Request.Browser.MajorVersion  < 7)
    { 
        //Show the message here
    }
    ...
}
else if (Request.Browser.Type.Contains("Firefox")) 
{
   //code to show message
}
else if (Request.Browser.Type.Contains("Chrome")) 
{
   //code to show message
}
```

Also check this **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx)** which has its own way of detecting the browser

> **Query the Browser property**, which contains an HttpBrowserCapabilities
>   object. This object gets information from the browser or client device
>   during an HTTP request, telling your application the type and level of
>   support the browser or client device offers. The object in turn
>   exposes information about browser capabilities using strongly typed
>   properties and a generic name-value dictionary.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
    string s = "Browser Capabilities\n"
        + "Type = "                    + browser.Type + "\n"
        + "Name = "                    + browser.Browser + "\n"
        + "Version = "                 + browser.Version + "\n"
        + "Major Version = "           + browser.MajorVersion + "\n"
        + "Minor Version = "           + browser.MinorVersion + "\n"
        + "Platform = "                + browser.Platform + "\n"
        + "Is Beta = "                 + browser.Beta + "\n"
        + "Is Crawler = "              + browser.Crawler + "\n"
        + "Is AOL = "                  + browser.AOL + "\n"
        + "Is Win16 = "                + browser.Win16 + "\n"
        + "Is Win32 = "                + browser.Win32 + "\n"
        + "Supports Frames = "         + browser.Frames + "\n"
        + "Supports Tables = "         + browser.Tables + "\n"
        + "Supports Cookies = "        + browser.Cookies + "\n"
        + "Supports VBScript = "       + browser.VBScript + "\n"
        + "Supports JavaScript = "     + 
            browser.EcmaScriptVersion.ToString() + "\n"
        + "Supports Java Applets = "   + browser.JavaApplets + "\n"
        + "Supports ActiveX Controls = " + browser.ActiveXControls 
              + "\n"
        + "Supports JavaScript Version = " +
            browser["JavaScriptVersion"] + "\n";

    TextBox1.Text = s;
}
```