# Unable to reliably use Google reCAPTCHA 2.0 and jquery 2.1.4 because of IE compatibility issues

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11, recaptcha, ie-compatibility-mode

I am struggling to find a way to get Google's reCAPTCHA 2.0 to reliably work for IE users.  Some IE users are getting the message:

"*Please upgrade to a supported browser to get a reCAPTCHA challenge.*"

Many posts here and elsewhere say to add the following meta tag to the page, which I have done:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;" />
```

Adding this tag did not fix the problem and asking users of the site to try and change their browser settings is not an option.

Is there something else that I can do?

I am also getting "*Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'*" errors in IE 11 and I suspect it's related to compatibility view as well. (jquery 2.1.4)

Answer (score 1):

First off, have you tried [removing the semi-colon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx#setmode)?

Second, the error you cited suggests you're viewing the page in compatibility view.  (You can check this by using the Emulation tab of the F12 tools.)

Are you deploying this to a local web page or an Intranet site (e.g your local network)?  If so, have you tried adding a [Mark of the Web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx) (MotW) to the page?  That tells IE to open page in the Internet zone which should, in turn, allow the `x-ua-compatible` header to take precedence.  (By default, IE opens Intranet pages in [Compatibility view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272454/ie11-document-mode-defaults-to-ie7-how-to-reset/27278277#27278277).)

If it is an intranet site or you have access to the web server headers, you can also [configure the server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676913(v=vs.85).aspx) to issue the `x-ua-compatible` directive instead of specifying within the page.

Comment: yes - tried with/without the semi-colon.  Yes-the problem is that it IS running compatibility mode and I am trying to force IE not to do that.  This is used both internally and externally. I will look into MotW. Is the server issued  'x-ua-compatible' directive a header that is set or something specific to an IIS server?  I am running linux/apache.

Comment: Well, the semi-colon isn't the official syntax, so definitely leave it out.  Also, there are some pretty [specific rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx#setmode) (look under the table) for the header in a webpage; make sure you're following those.  As far as the server-issued version, it's a [header you'd serve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc817573.aspx). To verify the zone of the web page, right-click a blank area on the page and then choose Properties from the shortcut menu.