# Javascript/JQuery: Get IE version and compatible version (if it is ON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

This would be a great help if someone knows how to figure out the correct IE version.

Here is what we have now. We have a web application. May of our users are using IE 11 or older versions and WITH compatible mode on. So now I have find out a way to log the correct browser version and the compatible version they are using.

After googling, I have tried many options (including below), but I am not getting the IE11. I am getting IE7.

```
I am using                       code                           output

---------                        ----                           -------

IE11, Compatible Ver:5       navigator.userAgent               MSIE 7.0

IE11, Compatible Ver:Edge    navigator.userAgent               rv:11

IE11, Compatible Ver:5       navigator.appVersion              MSIE 7.0

IE11, Compatible Ver:5       navigator.appVersion              rv:11





I want

IE11, Compatible Ver:5      <code/>                          MSIE 11, Comp: 5

IE11, Compatible Ver:Edge   <same code/>                     MSIE 11, Comp: Edge
```

I am trying to achieve it using javascript or JQuery. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: @someone who downvoted, it really hard for guys like you who downvotes without a comment... I would know who you are I will definitely ask Stackoverflow to restrict/block your account...

Answer (score -1):

The "MSIE" token in navigator.userAgent will tell you the compatibility version IE is using (except in IE11 with compatibility mode off, which doesn't have an MSIE token.)

However, the "Trident" token gives you a hint as to the actual IE version.

- Trident/4.0 -> IE 8
- Trident/5.0 -> IE 9
- Trident/6.0 -> IE 10
- Trident/7.0 -> IE 11

This token never changes, even in compatibility mode.

Comment: Thanks libertyernie for your answer. I will try. @someone who downvoted, it really hard for guys like you who downvotes without a comment... I would know who you are I will definitley ask Stackoverflow to restrict/block your account...

Comment: Got a solution in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791619/detect-ie10-compatibility-mode