# Detect IE 7 Emulate while running in IE 8+

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, internet-explorer

Due to some reason the application was designed to force the IE 7 rendering engine in IE 8+, using below META Tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

I want to apply some IE 7 specific styles like below.

```
 <!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
    #myElement
    {
       padding-bottom:49.00% !important;
    }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

[Code Reference](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

`I am opening the site in IE 8` and it emulates to IE 7 mode, but my styles are not getting applied here.

***How do i detect IE 7 Emulate  mode here?*** using jQuery(1.4.1) also welcome.

**Note:** *The application was designed long time back, it is in maintanance mode. So not possible to upgrade jQuery version*

Update: ***Finally I used***

```
navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Trident")!=-1 
&& document.documentMode==7
```

Comment: "*the application was designed to force the IE 7 rendering engine in IE 8+*" ... oh dear. That was your first mistake.

Comment: @Spudley, I already read [Detect IE8 Compatibility Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328963/detect-ie8-compatibility-mode). But how can i make it in programatically?

Comment: Are you sure your browser is in the right mode? If you've changed the compatibility mode in IE, this header won't magically reset it. Use F12 & check would mode you're in

Comment: @SimonHalsey, `BrowserMode IE 8 , Document Mode IE 7`

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional comment is incorrect:

```
 <!--[if lt IE 7]>

 should be

 <!--[if IE 7]>
```

The first one reads: All versions of IE *less than* 7

Comment: I updated with the code reference link. please check it